# Como criar condição de estilo no Jaspersoft Studio?

Tags: java, java-ee, ireport, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Como posso colocar uma condição de estilo no Jasper Studio verificando se o valor for positivo colocar verde em foreground, caso seja 0 ou negativo colocar vermelho no foreground?

Eu passo o seguinte para o HashMap datasource:

```
JRDataSource jrDataMovimentacoes = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(movimentacoes);
    BigDecimal jrSumLancamentos = lancamentoDao.getLancamentoSum(parameters);

    if(MoneyUtil.getStringMoneyValueWithComma(jrSumLancamentos).startsWith("-")){
        params.put("movSumValidator", "NEGATIVE");
    }else {
        params.put("movSumValidator", "POSITIVE");
    }

    params.put("movimentacoesSum", MoneyUtil.getStringMoneyValueWithComma(jrSumLancamentos));
```

Condição que coloquei no style:

```
<style name="MovSumValidator">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$P{movSumValidator}.equals("NEGATIVE")]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" forecolor="#C70704" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <pen lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#030302"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.1"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.1"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.1"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.1"/>
            </box>
        </style>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$P{movSumValidator}.equals("POSITIVE")]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" forecolor="#1AB305" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.1" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.1" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.1" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.1" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
        </style>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

Campo que deve aparecer o valor positivo ou negativo com a cor determinada:

```
<textField pattern="">
            <reportElement key="" style="MovSumValidator" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="638" y="190" width="164" height="15" forecolor="#000000" uuid="1eb194f9-c922-45ea-8f6a-1d3b4fd7a425">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.1" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.1" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.1" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="8"/>
                <paragraph rightIndent="2"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{movimentacoesSum}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

Em resumo, verifico na service caso o valor seja positivo ou negativo e passo um parâmetro adicional no hashmap.

Mesmo assim nada acontece, o relatório é impresso sem validar o que fiz.

Comment: Você aplicou o estilo a algum campo? como está ficando o resultado? sempre verde, sempre vermelho ou nenhum.

Comment: O relatório é gerado com a cor padrão, não acontece a verificação. Acredito que o método startsWith() não esteja sendo lido. Vou tentar verificar com o condicional que você mostrou no post abaixo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Crie um novo estilo**

[image: Criando Estilo]

**2. Selecione o novo estilo criado, e altere o seu nome conforme imagens abaixo**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**3. Clique com o botão direito do mouse sobre o novo estilo criado e depois clique em criar novo estilo condicional conforme segue nas imagens...**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**4. Clique com o botão direito do mouse sobre o novo estilo condicioal criado e depois clique em mostrar propriedades**

**5. Selecione a aba "Estilo" em expressão condicional.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**6. Na expressão você pode colocar a condição que desejar, nas imagem abaixo está ilustrada a sua necessidade.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**7. Altere para a aba Aparência e selecione a cor desejada para "Foreground".**

**8. Repita o processo para criar a condição para a outra cor.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**9. Aplique o estilo criado no campo desejado conforme imagens abaixo.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**10. Execute o relatório e terá o resultado esperado.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não consegui fazer funcionar ainda, super esquisito, deve ter algo que não estou conseguindo enxergar.

Comment: O seu parâmetro esta com o tipo java.math.BigDecimal? talvez você esqueceu de alterar, por padrão fica como String.

Comment: Consegui descobrir o problema, a condicional estava funcional o detalhe é que o jasper por algum motivo quando gerava o input mais abaixo era sobrescrito com a cor padrão preto.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, caso saiba o motivo do problema, seria legal compartilhar como resolveu, editando a pergunta ou criando uma resposta.